Hot and cold water line 3 inches too short
I bought a new kitchen faucet but the hot and cold water lines are not long enough, they're three inches too short. Replacing the hot cold water lines with longer lines is not possible on the specific faucet. How can I connect them so I can use my kitchen sink?

Pigtails to lengthen each line.

PLease post photos for a better answer.

Pretty sure you can buy flexbile extension hoses.

If you have the normal 3/8 compression connections on the shut off valves, you can use the Flexible 3/8 m/f extentions
If you cannot find the Male/female lines, a female/female line and a male connector will work to connect everything.

You need a male to male 1/2 connector to be able to extend the water pipes.
Then you need some length extra flexible pipe to reach the destination.
